# Matching with out replacement one to two with SQL

Tags: sql

```
Name        Interest
----------------------
Carol       Books
Carol       Dancing
Carol       Sports  
Carol       Movies   
Carol       Music    
Sue         Books
Sue         Dancing
Sue         Sports    
Sue         Music 
Sue        Painting    
SAM         Books
SAM         Dancing
SAM         Sports    
SAM         Music 
SAM        Painting
```

I have a very big data set. And I want to find for each name two distinct interest. But two individuals should not have the same interest.

I want the resulting table look like this

```
Name        Interest1   Interest 2  
-----------------------------------
Carol       Books       Sports
Sue         Music       Painting        
SAM         Dancing      NAN
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

We could handle this requirement using row number:

```
WITH names AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) rn
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM yourTable) t
),
interests AS (
    SELECT Interest,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Interest) rn1,
        FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Interest) + 1) / 2) rn2
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Interest FROM yourTable) t
)

SELECT
    n.Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN i.rn1 % 2 = 1 THEN i.Interest END) AS Interest1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN i.rn1 % 2 = 0 THEN i.Interest END) AS Interest2
FROM names n
LEFT JOIN interests i
    ON n.rn = rn2
GROUP BY
    n.Name;
```

[image: screen capture from demo]

### Demo

Note: The syntax and demo I used are for SQL Server, but the above should run on any SQL database which supports `ROW_NUMBER`, with little modification.